# Closing the current window and opening a new one, have to be done in actionPerformed() method?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I am making a server/client chat system with sockets and I am using MVC to separate my concerns. I am used to Web MVC where I can easily redirect the user when I want to go to a different page but I am not used to this in Java.

The scenario is the user puts in some data, clicks a button, the action listener in the controller gets triggered and I get the data I need from the view and now I want to close the current window and open a new one, is the correct way to do this within the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)` method? or is there a better way? It just feels wrong to me for some reason.

Thanks.

Comment: For better help sooner, please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: Putting aside my concerns about throwing a bunch of windows at the user, the control would handle the window swapping. I don't know how your code is"wired" together, so for now that's about as specific as I can get.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It is the only place I can think of doing it because I get the data from the view, run a method of one of my services and if it returns true I then need to close the current view and load up a new one. Is this how it is usually done?

Comment: I don't know about"usually", but it should be the control's responsibility. The control would change the state of the model. The view would respond to this change in state.